# wait for user input in swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, wait

I have a few classes that use swing GUI and one JFrame that displays all of the GUI and all of GUI have an action listener for the Jbuttons and  an ItemListener for the Jcheckboxes that cause various things to happen. Some of these buttons and checkboxes are other sub-classes that extend them.

when I do this

```
Public class SomeClass{        
   SomeClass(){
     // some code here
     methodCalled();
   }

 public void methodCalled(){
    //more code here
    new BazarGui();
    new MapGui();
 }
}
```

How do I actually get bazar GUI to wait for the user to click some buttons or checkboxes with out having the program go right to map GUI? they both work fine on their own but when one is called after the other only the second one shows. Would make the GUIs for the bazaar and map be JDialogs as opposed to JPanels and then adding them to the JFrame solve this problem?

Comment: *"Would making the GUIs for the bazar and map be JDialogs as opposed to JPanels and then adding them to the JFrame solve this problem?" You cannot add a `JDialog` to a `JFrame`. But you **can**` add a `JPanel` to a `JDialog` and display it. If the dialog is modal, the code statements that set it visible will stop until it is closed.

Comment: A modal dialog will block the execution of the code at the point the dialog is made visible (but allow the user to interact with the dialog).  General recommendation is to use `JPanel` or other containers to build the basic UI up and then add them to whatever top level container you need later, it makes them more flexible and re-usable